# ASP on button click validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have this code inside GridView:

```
<asp:TemplateField >
<ItemTemplate>
<input type="button"  id="Button98"
    usesubmitbehavior="true"
    Text="pavadinimas" 
    onclientclick="ConfirmOnDelete()"
    onclick="location.href='SMSReport.aspx?data=<%#Eval("data")%>&amp;db=1'" 
    />
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function ConfirmOnDelete()
        {
          if (confirm("Are you sure?")==true)
            return true;
          else
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I'm not sure why, but onclientclick part is not working. I was looking and trying many solutions, but non is working. Any ideas how to add check on click?

Comment: Your input is not a server-side control, so there is no onclientclick and onclick, only onclick which happens client side. Do you want to have validation and then execution of location.href code? If so, merge them together into one function

Comment: @Andrei Could you be more specific how to do that? Or maybe you could give some code example?

Comment: Shaminder provided a good answer below, he just did not clarify well enough about the script tag. I added a comment there, this should resolve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnClientClick` only works for asp server button control (`System.Web.UI.WebControls`) , but you are using the html button control so, and put your javascript code seperately which means that put your script tag outside your `GridView` control. Try the below code:

```
    <asp:TemplateField >
        <ItemTemplate>
        <input type="button"  id="Button98"
            Text="pavadinimas" value="delete"
            onclick="ConfirmOnDelete('<%#Eval("data")%>');" 
            />

     </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>

            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                function ConfirmOnDelete(para)
                {
                  if (confirm("Are you sure?")==true)
                   location.href='SMSReport.aspx?data=' + para + '&amp;db=1';
                  else
                    return false;
                }
            </script>
```

Comment: Now i get Error: 
''Parser Error Message: System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection must have items of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlField'. 'script' is of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl'.''

Comment: Like before nothing happens.

Comment: try replaacing this `onclick="ConfirmOnDelete('<%#Eval("data")%>');"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92129/discussion-between-shaminder-s-aujla-and-macb3th).

Comment: This script tag should be taken out of the gridview. Place it somewhere in the bottom of the page, and otherwise this should get you going fine

Comment: I put code in bottom of the page, then in top, still nothing happens.

Comment: @Macb3th try the updated code, ' was missing in the end of location string.

Comment: Thanks, now it works fine. @ShaminderSAujla you saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">      
    <input type="button" id="btn_11" runat="server" onclick="ConfirmOnDelete(); location.href = 'http://www.google.com'" />
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function ConfirmOnDelete() {
            if (confirm("Are you sure?") == true)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    </script>         
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue last week,

your asp.net button should have an OnClientClick="DoValidation(); click event assigned to is and thenin your js file you should have

asp.button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClientClick="DoValidation()" runat="server" Text="Search" Height="36px" />
```

javascript

```
function DoValidation(parameter) {

 //your validation code here

if (valid == true) {
    __doPostBack('btnSave', parameter);
   }
}
```

Comment: but OP has no asp button, having simple html input button